# Javascript toLocaleString onKeyUp Event

Tags: javascript, converters, currency, onkeyup

I need some help to fix this issue, I'm trying to print out `value` from `<input>` tag while typing, and it should print out with thousand separator, but it return number like I input, more precisely **it doesn't work**. How I have to fix this...?

```js
function cDes(e) {
  var k = e.currentTarget;
  var prc = k.value; //example value: 123456789
  var prc_f = prc.toLocaleString('de-DE');
  var oDiv = document.getElementById('cOut');
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (prc.length < 1) {
      oDiv.innerHTML = 'FREE';
    } else {
      oDiv.innerHTML = prc_f; //expected output value: 123.456.789
    }
  } else {
    oDiv.innerHTML = '...';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='number' id='price' onKeyUp='cDes(event)'>

<div id='cOut'></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the input string to Number before using [`Number.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```
var prc_f = Number(prc).toLocaleString('de-DE');
```

Example:

```js
// get a reference to the element once
var oDiv = document.getElementById('cOut');

function cDes(e) {
  var prc = e.target.value; //example value: 123456789
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (prc.length < 1) {
      oDiv.innerHTML = 'FREE';
    } else {
      // you only need to convert the input when you display it
      oDiv.innerHTML = Number(prc).toLocaleString('de-DE'); //expected output value: 123.456.789
    }
  } else {
    oDiv.innerHTML = '...';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='number' id='price' onKeyUp='cDes(event)'>

<div id='cOut'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer may deviate a little from your expectation , but you if objective is to show the price along with symbol , you can use [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

```js
function cDes(e) {
  var k = e.currentTarget;
  var prc = k.value; //example value: 123456789
  var prc_f = nf.format(prc);
  var oDiv = document.getElementById('cOut');
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if (prc.length < 1) {
      oDiv.innerHTML = 'FREE';
    } else {
      oDiv.innerHTML = prc_f; //expected output value: 123.456.789
    }
  } else {
    oDiv.innerHTML = '...';
  }
}
var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
});
```

```html
<input type='number' id='price' onKeyUp='cDes(event)'>

<div id='cOut'></div>
```